# How to test a data migration is done correctly?

Tags: data-migration

How can I check that a data migration project (data migration from excel sheets to salesforce) is done completely right ?

Comment: @Ricky You can try close.io to migrate data from excel to salesforce and also can track the status of the Migration

Comment: the data migration is already done , I just don't know to test if it is done completely correct or not?
for example I found some duplicate records right now so I found that I must do a deep test to be sure about everything

Comment: @Rickey What tool did you use for data migration?

Comment: @Rickey Try Apex coding to query the duplicate record and process it if you want to delete it or you can try Custom report type on the object and delete the duplicate records.

Comment: can you take a look at these codes and advice me which one is better :

select name,last name count(*) from Contact
group by name
having count(*)>1
___________________________________________

List<AggregateResult> acc=[SELECT Name, Lastname count(Id) FROM Contact GROUP BY Name HAVING count(Id)>1];
for(AggregateResult aggres : acc)
{
System.debug('Finding duplicate names'+aggres);
}

Comment: Its always better to do the cleanup manually using a dataloader, extract, cleanse data and upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the steps to validate data after migration ,

1. Generating reports on source & target to verify record count
2. Checking data integrity by verifying some test records.
3. Check if the duplicate already exist in source & if you have already moved in duplicates then use some free apps on appexchange to identify & eliminate the same.